# Neo4j automatic (numeric) indexing

Tags: lucene, indexing, neo4j

If I enable automatic indexing on for example `latitude` and `longitude` fields (type: `double`) I can't do this query

```
autoIndex.query(
            QueryContext.numericRange(
                    'longitude',
                    16.598145,
                    46.377254
            )
    );
```

`autoIndex` is defined as `graphDb.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().getAutoIndex()`.
Simply the result size is `size=0`.

---

Other queries like

```
autoIndex.get(...)
```

or

```
autoIndex.query('id', new QueryContext("*").sort(sort))
```

work just fine.

---

If I however manually add index `locations_index` with

```
    ValueContext latValue = new ValueContext(node.getProperty('latitude')).indexNumeric();
    ValueContext lonValue = new ValueContext(node.getProperty('longitude')).indexNumeric();

    locationsIndex.add(node, 'latitude', latValue);
    locationsIndex.add(node, 'longitude', lonValue);
```

for each latitude/longitude in database then the query works.

My question is - is there a way to automatically index numeric field as `ValueContext.indexNumeric()`? Shouldn't that be automatic?